# Python Str object is not callable in Spyder

Tags: python

I have been trying to use str() function to convert the integer to string in Spyder (python 2.7). Every time I got `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

For example, I wrote this simple code to test it and I got the same error:

```
x = 5
print str(x)
```

Can someone help me in this

Comment: You probably created another variable called `str`.  If you run that code in a brand-new interpreter session, it shouldn't give that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overwritten the built-in `str` somewhere in your code.

```
>>> str = 'foo'   # overwriting the builtin `str`
>>> x = 5
>>> print str(x)  # equivalent to 'foo'(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: I checked my code and I didn't find str anywhere! is there another way to convert int to String?

Comment: @Nasser: Check your code again.  Do you import any modules like `from whatever import *`?  If so check those modules as well.  Also, before `print str(x)` do `print repr(str)`.  That should help you figure things out.